# where do i find dse.jar for cassandra-spark join operation?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax

i'm working on cassandra joins using sql. i found that dse.jar is needed for the operation but couldn't find the path to download the jar. i googled and found that we need to maually download and add it to the project, but no one has said where to download the jar from. 
[http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.6/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkJavaApi.html?scroll=sparkJavaApi__dsejar_unique_1][1]

Comment: It's part of the DSE installation

Comment: I'm working on windows environment. found the jar in [dse.jar Download path](https://academy.datastax.com/downloads/download-previous-versions#dl-community-drivers) downloaded the tarball and found the jar in lib file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't download the jar individually. It's usually under `/usr/share/dse/dse.jar` in package installations of Datastax Enterprise

Comment: I'm working on windows environment. found the jar in [dse.jar Download path](https://academy.datastax.com/downloads/download-previous-versions#dl-community-drivers) downloaded the tarball and found the jar in lib file.